login to Azure VM using Azure AD User, getting error "The sign-in method you are trying to use isn't allowed. Try different sign-in method"
I am trying to connect to Azure VM using Azure AD User, but getting below error.
"The sign-in method you are trying to use isn't allowed. Try different sign-in method"
I have enabled Azure Entra while creating Azure VM.
Please help.
I have tried creating new VM with Azure Entra Enabled and also gave Virtual Machine Admin access to the Azure AD User.
I am expecting user to get logged in to VM using Azure AD Credentials.

check if "Virtual Machine User Login" role assigned to user @pradeep

Thanks,Yes I have given Virtual Machine Admin role to the use

Have you added the user to the RDP group and disabled NLA, refer this Stack link.

Yes I have added used to VM Admin group and also disabled NLA on VM, but still getting same error.


"The sign-in method you are trying to use isn't allowed. Try different sign-in method"

The above error usually appears, because by default you cannot sign in locally with any user that hasn't administrator permissions on Azure VM.
To resolve the issue, you may follow the below steps.

Login to VM with Local Admin User

Open run and type gpedit.msc and press Enter

Open Group Policy Editor by navigate to: Computer Configuration > Windows Settings> Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment.

At the Allow log on locally Properties  window, click on Add User or Group.

Add users to allow all users, or add specific users to permit only certain individuals.




Finally, open the Deny log on locally policy and ensure it is empty.



Close the Group Policy Editor and restart the server.
Run the gpupdate /force command to apply the local group policy settings.
After updating the group policy settings, restart and log in with the Azure AD user.

Reference:  Sign in to a Windows virtual machine in Azure by using Microsoft Entra ID including passwordless
How do I login to an Azure AD Joined VM using Azure AD Credentials on an Windows Server 2019?
